# Keep alignments after exporting HTML table to excel

Tags: html, css, export-to-excel

I'm exporting HTML table to excel in my UI.
How can I set the alignments to the exported excel in my code?
I have used inline styles in my table for this, but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

HTML:
Export Table data into Excel
JS:
    $scope.exportData = function () {
        var blob = new Blob([document.getElementById('exportable').innerHTML], {
            type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet;charset=utf-8"
        });
        saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
    };

Comment: How can we solve your problem without seeing any line of code? How does your UI look like? How do you do the export? Whats your CSS?

Comment: My crystal ball is broken, I'm afraid. You will need to supply code and data samples. Please edit your question for that. Do NOT put more details into comments.